# Performan Set difference operation on two arrays

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to perform set difference operation.
Eg.

```
var a = ['a', 'b'], tw = ['b', 'c'], cn = ['a', 'b']
var zz = a - tw // => zz should be `['a']`
var zz = a - cn // => zz should be `[]`
```

Comment: Should a - tw be ['a'. 'c']?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe nope only element "a" , a-b is different to b -a

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
   let a = new Set(['a', 'b']);
   let tw = new Set(['b', 'c']);
   let cn = new Set(['a', 'b'])

   let diff1 = new Set([...a].filter(x => !tw.has(x)));
   let diff2 = new Set([...a].filter(x => !cn.has(x)));
```

Using underscore,

```
_(['a', 'b']).difference(['b', 'c']);
_(['a', 'b']).difference(['a', 'b']);
```